# list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

Tags: python, numpy

I have matrix like this:

```
print(sent_vectors[1])
[-1.17820399  0.46562683 -0.57934981 -0.78578004 -0.56564459  0.33715023
 -0.56717469  0.82579453  0.52400108 -0.59714594  0.14502474  0.44333297
 -0.71063957 -0.18717706 -0.47924724 -0.61488901 -0.19839954 -0.5482594
  0.35703259  0.15601261 -0.15312789  0.08714889  0.83434086 -0.59783169
  0.61747206 -0.16931582  0.13103572  0.1438039  -0.15157178 -1.2203296
  0.31373093  0.89667472 -0.17520199  0.48635741 -0.11917028 -0.19563493
 -0.59079649  1.08398885  0.23845113  0.75308501 -0.52543743  0.63864713
 -1.28121311 -0.27246536 -0.40900175 -0.82675008 -0.60381615  0.88978195
  NaN -0.56387159]
```

My question is how to find whether the matrix contains NaN values or not?
If it contains NaN values print that matrix? please help me out. I tried thus by using:

```
i=1;
for i in sent_vectors[i]:
    a=sent_vectors[i]
    np.where(np.isnan(a))
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

ERROR : list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

Comment: Why are you using `i` in two different ways?  `for i in sent_vectors[i]` - once to select an element of `sent_vectors` and then as the iteration variable.  That second is probably a float, which gives a problem in the next indexing `a=...`

Comment: I suspect you want `for a in sent_vectors[1]: idx = np.where(np.isnan(a)`.  As it is you aren't doing anything with the result of `np.where`.  Why are you doing it?

Comment: Actually length of sent_vectors  is 364171, so for each and every sent_vectors[i], i need to check whether it has any NaN values or not? If it has print that i value..This is my question

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you have a long list of arrays, some of which may contain `np.nan`.  Let's make a small test case:

```
In [617]: alist = [np.array([.1,.2,np.nan]), np.array([2,3,.2]), np.ones(3), np.zeros(3), np.array([np.nan,.1,2])]
In [618]: alist
Out[618]: 
[array([0.1, 0.2, nan]),
 array([2. , 3. , 0.2]),
 array([1., 1., 1.]),
 array([0., 0., 0.]),
 array([nan, 0.1, 2. ])]
```

We can test for `nan` in one of those arrays:

```
In [619]: np.isnan(alist[0])
Out[619]: array([False, False,  True])
```

We can iterate over the arrays, and print the ones that have `nan`:

```
In [620]: for i,a in enumerate(alist):
     ...:     idx = np.where(np.isnan(a))[0]
     ...:     if len(idx):print(i,idx)
     ...:     
0 [2]
4 [0]
```

If the arrays all have the same length, we can combine them into one 2d array:

```
In [621]: arr = np.stack(alist)
In [622]: arr
Out[622]: 
array([[0.1, 0.2, nan],
       [2. , 3. , 0.2],
       [1. , 1. , 1. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [nan, 0.1, 2. ]])

In [623]: np.isnan(arr)
Out[623]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]])

In [624]: _.any(axis=1)    # check for rows with a nan
Out[624]: array([ True, False, False, False,  True])
In [625]: np.where(_)
Out[625]: (array([0, 4]),)
```

or `where` applied to the whole array:

```
In [626]: np.where(np.isnan(arr))
Out[626]: (array([0, 4]), array([2, 0]))
```

---

I can reproduce your error message with:

```
In [627]: for i in alist[0]:
     ...:     a = alist[i]
     ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-627-b5ff2521aef0> in <module>()
      1 for i in alist[0]:
----> 2     a = alist[i]
      3 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

Note that is occurs in `a = alist[i]` line.  **You really should have included that information in your question.**

The `i` at this point is:

```
In [628]: i
Out[628]: 0.1
```

the first element of `alist[0]`.  You may need to review how iteration over a list works in Python.  `for i in x:` produces elements of `x`, not the indices.  It does not make sense to follow that by `x[i]`.  `for i in range(3): x[i]` is ok.  So is `for i,v in enumerate(x): x[i]`.

Comment: print(sent_vectors[270503])
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]

Comment: I found this is filled with nan, but how to replace it with 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for existence of NaN in an array/matrix using [`np.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

Here's the code to check each row for presence of `NaN`:

```
boolean_mask = np.empty(sent_vectors.shape)
boolean_mask = np.isnan(sent_vectors)

for idx, row in enumerate(boolean_mask):
      if np.any(row):
          print("NaN found @ row: ", idx)
          print("Row: ", sent_vectors[idx])
      else:
          continue
```

Comment: So, first i have to convert it to numpy array

Comment: But here, I have large data like 364k rows . In each row I have a such type of matrix. My Question is how to check which row of the matrix can contain NaN values?

Comment: I tried to search using this code:
i=1;
for i in sent_vectors[i]:
    a=sent_vectors[i]
    np.where(np.isnan(a))
    print(i)
    i += 1

Comment: Great Work!!! But In my data set I have 364k matrix like this. For this how to check ??

Comment: sent_vectors dim 364171 x 50

Comment: Actually length of sent_vectors is 364171, so for each and every sent_vectors[i], i need to check whether it has any NaN values or not? If it has print that i value..This is my question

Comment: print(sent_vectors[270503]) [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]

Comment: I found this is filled with nan, but how to replace it with 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way

```
contains_nan = numpy.isnan(sent_vectors).any()
if contains_nan:
    print(sent_vectors)
```